# Editing OS names in /etc/default/grub - where is the OS name read from?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Where does the entry

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
```

take the names from?

Here is why this is not a duplicate of "How to safely change OS name in grub boot menu?":

I know already that the names assigned to the OSs in the GRUB boot menu can be changed by commenting

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
```

and replacing the entry by

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Some other name"
```

(in inverted commas).

All explanations I have found just say:

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian -
```

"This line simply retrieves the name in the menu entry."
Fair enough! But I would like to know:
Where does this command retrieve the actual name from? The names must be contained in some file in plain text!

Comment: This variable has nothing to do with the boot entries' names, it only describes which system is providing/managing the GRUB boot menu. And the command `lsb_release -i -s` will simply output the operating system's name, i.e. "Ubuntu".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I `strace` the command `lsb_release -i -s`...

```
strace -o strace.out lsb_release -i -s
```

I find (from output file `strace.out`) that it is reading `/etc/lsb-release`

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
```

The output of `lsb_release -i -s` is `Ubuntu`

The redirection `2> /dev/null` sends any errors from the command to data oblivion

The operator `||` means if (and only if) the first command failed, do the second one:

```
first command || second command
```

So if `lsb_release -i -s` errors out, the errors go to `/dev/null` and the command `echo Debian` is executed. The output of that is `Debian`

So to summarise:

**If `lsb_release -s -i` can give us the name of the current system, then use that and display the output. If not, just call it "Debian"**

The file `/etc/default/grub` is used to generate the config file read by GRUB (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) when `update-grub` is called, so it is read when the real root filesystem is mounted.

You must run `sudo update-grub` after editing the file for any changes to take effect.

Comment: you definitely have the superior answer.

Comment: ^_^ thanks @user557506 I'm really glad it was helpful for you

Comment: I followed the steps you indicated and the output was verbatim the same.  In the actual (grub2) boot menu, however, the name differs from those containedd in /etc/lsb-release. It has apparently retained the name of the live DVD and reads: "tuxtrans 16.04 live cd GNU/Linux". So where does that come from?

Comment: @user557506 I'm not sure why it has that name, but GRUB's real config file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is only updated using configuration from `/etc/default/grub` when `update-grub` is called, so do `sudo update-grub` and see if it changes

Comment: Did the trick! After running    update-grub,    the name I wanted to change appeared in    /etc/default/grub    and I managed to change it there. Thanks again for your detailed instructions.

Comment: @user557506 made a small update to the end, since obviously that part was not clear enough :)

Answer (score 2):

**lsb_release** is an internal command to obtain the Linux Distro and version (release number). How the command works and where it gets the information from can be duplicated by you.

In terminal type `cat /proc/version`:

```
Linux version 4.7.3-040703-generic (kernel@tangerine) (gcc version 6.2.0 20160901 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11) ) #201609070334 SMP Wed Sep 7 07:36:45 UTC 2016
```

**Ubuntu** appears in /proc/version but not the way it appears on grub menus. So we move on....

Now type `cat /etc/issue`:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

This is where **lsb_release** is probably getting the Linux Distro, because **Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS** is what appears on my grub menu.

Before indirectly affecting the variable **$GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR** (referenced in your question) by forcing **/etc/issue** to a different constant, consider this code within `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`:

```
set_default_theme(){
    case $GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR in
        Tanglu|Ubuntu|Kubuntu)
            # Set a monochromatic theme for Tanglu/Ubuntu.
            echo "${1}set menu_color_normal=white/black"
            echo "${1}set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray"
```

Changing *Ubuntu* to *My Cool Linux* might appear on the menu okay but internal grub code for themes and coloring would be broken above. Not to mention all the other "things" that might break inside grub plus outside in your other applications and the OS.

**Edit 1:**

As I learned this morning at [command-to-show-linux-version](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/command-to-show-linux-version/) and then discovered @Zanna has already given an excellent answer above, the command **lsb_release** retrieves text from `/etc/lsb-release`.