# how to tell GRUB to show the user preferred names of OS'es. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: grub2

I am new to Ubuntu.
I am Using Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows10.
I have gone through the below Q&A and could able to change the name of Ubuntu,

[Editing OS names in /etc/default/grub - where is the OS name read from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822757/editing-os-names-in-etc-default-grub-where-is-the-os-name-read-from)

But

1. if i edit the Ubuntu OS name to my choice, it is then adding "GNU/Linux" at the end. for ex. if i want "Ubuntu 18.04" it is then showing as "Ubuntu 18.04 GNU/Linux". how to avoid this text "GNU/Linux"
2. how to edit the name to my choice which is shown as "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)"

[image]
[image]

Update:
I Confirm about the text "GNU/Linux" is solved by @Terrance comments.
I still need to try about windows entry.

[image]

Final Update:
Solved.

I thank @Terrance, @Oldfred, @WinEunuuchs2Unix.
All the three methods are working great.
i felt the small script is awesome and very very easy to use. which is written by WinEuuuchs2Unix.

[image]

Comment: I don't have anything official, but if you look at my answer from a long time ago it is the OS-Prober files that set the names:  https://askubuntu.com/a/666318/231142  I could be off though for the Ubuntu name though.

Comment: For windows naming I will try it and get back to you. But about adding the text "GNU/ Linux" do you have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: I am looking and testing some things right now.  I will let you know.  =)

Comment: Thank you. I will try and get back to you. But it's late night now 2am. Morning I will workout. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looks like I found something for you.  In the file `/etc/grub.d/10_liunx` on line 45 it is if you change the name of Ubuntu or whatever it shows 4 lines up that is where it adds the `GNU/Linux`.  You can copy that line and paste it below or above it, then comment out the original line and I bet that will fix what you are seeing.

Comment: I will make it now.

Comment: Make sure on the new line you remove the `GNU/Linux` off it.

Comment: Yes, i confirm your comment about "GNU/Linux" is solved point no. 1 of my Q. I need to try for windows entry. I will do it in few hours. Thanks for your quick response. I have updated my question. please have a look.

Comment: @Terrance, i have gone through your answer in first comment. But not able to understand where to change, here is the file /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/W53x644qdb/ Please have a look.

Comment: I am sorry, it is in the `/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/20microsoft` file

Comment: ya, trying now..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyWuF.jpg. Its almost done. now we need to avoid the text "(on /dev/sda1)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to break a taboo but the easiest way is modifying `grub.cfg`.

Create the script `my-update-grub` containing:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: my-update-grub
# PATH: /mnt/e/bin
# DESC: Run update-grub and then rename menu entries
# DATE: July 13, 2018. (yah it's a Friday)

# Must not prefix with sudo when calling script
if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then
    zenity --error --text "You must call this script using sudo. Aborting."
    exit 99
fi

#sudo update-grub # Optional remove # in column 1

sed -i "s|Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)|Windows 10|g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sed -i "s|Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)|Windows 10 original|g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sed -i "s|Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (18.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p6)|Ubuntu 18.04|g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg

exit 0
```

- Change comment `PATH:` to where you put script, probably `/usr/local/bin`
- Change `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)` to your menu option.
- Change `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (18.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p6)` to your menu option.
- Delete line with `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)` which probably isn't needed.
- Remove `#` in front of `# sudo update-grub` so you don't have to type that manually before typing `sudo my-update-grub`.
- Make the script executable. In your case use: `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/GrubTextEntries`
- After every kernel update, run `sudo my-grub-update`

---

I tested this on my system first but, if in doubt, backup first using:

```
sudo cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.sav
```

---

## Before and After

The images are a little skewed because I'm limited to capturing them at distorted 1600x1200 in Virtualbox in Ubuntu 16.04:

### Before

[image: Before]

### After

[image: ResizedGrub2.png]

Comment: Shoot: forgot to tell you `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/GrubTextEntries` to make the script executable.I'll update the answer.

Comment: If you run `sudo update-grub` alot, remove the `#` in front of the command in the script. Then you only need to run `sudo GrubTextEntries` which calls `sudo update-grub` itself. However, when Ubuntu installs a new kernel you will need to run `sudo GrubTextEntries` to get menu updated.

Comment: @PRATAP You no longer have to run `sudo update-grub` followed by `sudo GrubTextEntries`. You only have to run `sudo GrubTextEntries` which calls `sudo update-grub` automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to change Ubuntu.

sudo nano -B /etc/default/grub

```
#GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Xubuntu-12.04-amd64 Precise"
```

sudo update-grub

If you want to change other installs, turn off os-prober in /etc/default/grub, by adding this line:

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true

And then in 40_custom you can put anything you want.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

[How to update grub on a dual boot machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine/848614#848614)

I also can boot ISO directly from grub.

[How do I boot an ISO file from my drive using grub2 on UEFI machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines/1025686#1025686)

I also am converting hd1,gpt4 type entries to use search & labels. Too often I have to manually change drive as I boot, as plugging in USB changes drive number.

[How to add a GRUB2 menu entry for booting installed Ubuntu on a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359)

cosmic_b is my install of cosmic on drive sdb, so I labeled it cosmic_b.

```
menuentry "Cosmic 18.10 on sdb12 test" {
    search --set=root --label cosmic_b --hint hd2,gpt12
    configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
}
```

Comment: Hi, seems this is the answer. I am trying the answer but stuck at editing 40_custom file. I dont know from where to copy paste menuentrys here in this text file. it contains 5 lines.

Comment: @PRATAP Copy  from `/boot/grub.cfg`

Comment: yes, i got one entry for windows in /boot/grub/grub.cfg....trying now..

Comment: @mook765 i think i have to workout much in this method. i am worried about 06_os-prober as it is already there in /etc/grub.d and i am worried if i have to save as 40_os-prober.. I felt Terrance comments are easy to achieve what i want.

Comment: Grub uses files in number order. So if you want your manual entries first, use 06_custom. If you want yours last use 40_custom. You can backup grub.cfg generated by os_prober & copy entries from it into 40_custom. Once you know they work then you can change descriptions. Examples from grub manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&p=13767911#post13767911