# Change description of OS

Tags: grub2, 20.04

I´m learning the basics of Ubuntu, currently I have Windows 7 & 10 installed and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed in a virtual machine.

I´m trying to edit the **description of the operating system** I have installed by executing the terminal with the comand `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/10_linux`. Then I know I need to change this bit of code I show on the screenshot, but I have been trying changing everything and nothing seems to work, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you and apologize for my bad English.

Screenshot of the config file from `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/10_linux`.
[image]

Comment: may this related? https://askubuntu.com/q/1054936/739431

Comment: Link above has this, which is what you normally change. `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=` in grub. I change mine. `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=kubuntu` and comment out the default that grub has.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you edit files in `/etc/grub.d`, you need to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to create a new configuration file (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) and thus apply the changes you made with your edit.